# What is this called? "allows the programmer to call a method on a subclass even though they only have a reference to a superclass"

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism

I think it's polymorphism or inheritance. And can I please have a basic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ParentClass {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Parent Class Method");
    }
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Child Class Method");
    }
}
```

Now in your main code you can do the following:

```
ParentClass class = new ChildClass();
class.doSomething();
```

This would print out "Child Class Method" because the ChildClass method overrides the ParentClass method.

- "ChildClass extends ParentClass" is an example of inheritance.
- "ParentClass class = new ChildClass();" is an example of
  polymorphism.

Still confused?

Comment: Ok I understand that. So would the answer to the original question be polymorphism?

Comment: I would think so, yes.

Comment: I think that's the most correct answer.  Inheritance is a prerequisite to having this kind of polymorphism, but it is the polymorphism which enables invocation of method overrides from a superclass reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your particular case is known as Dynamic Polymorphism.
(Method overloading would be a case of Static polymorphism).